# Having trouble passing data to Highcharts

Tags: php, highcharts

I am trying to pull financial stock data of multiple companies from CSVs and display the data as separate series in a Highcharts/Highstocks line chart. I have the sources setup and I am able to pull data + convert to JSON, but I am having trouble passing the data off to Highcharts. I believe I am not using the most efficient method of preparing the data for Highcharts use, and I am hoping someone can give me direction on what I've done incorrectly. Please take a look at my code and make me aware of any inefficiencies or glaring errors you see.

PHP code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

$stocks = array('MSFT' => 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=MSFT', 'AAPL' => 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=AAPL', 'FB' => 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=FB');
$stocks_data = array();

foreach ($stocks as $key=>$stock) {
    $fh = fopen($stock, 'r');
    $header = fgetcsv($fh);

    $varname = $key . '_data';

    $$varname  = array();
    while ($line = fgetcsv($fh)) {
        ${$varname}[count($$varname)] = array_combine($header, $line);
    }

    fclose($fh);
}

foreach($MSFT_data as $val){
    $MSFT[]   = strtotime($val['Date']) * 1000 . ', ' . (float)$val['Close']; //sets the date as a javascript timestamp
}
$MSFT = json_encode($MSFT);

foreach($AAPL_data as $val){
    $AAPL[]   = strtotime($val['Date']) * 1000 . ', ' . (float)$val['Close']; //sets the date as a javascript timestamp
}
$AAPL = json_encode($AAPL);

foreach($FB_data as $val){
    $FB[]   = strtotime($val['Date']) * 1000 . ', ' . (float)$val['Close']; //sets the date as a javascript timestamp
}
$FB = json_encode($FB);
```

JS code:

```
$(function () {
    var seriesOptions = [],
        yAxisOptions = [],
        colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors;

    seriesOptions[0] = {
        name: 'MSFT',
        data: <? php echo $MSFT; ?>
    };

    seriesOptions[1] = {
        name: 'AAPL',
        data: <? php echo $AAPL; ?>
    };

    seriesOptions[2] = {
        name: 'FB',
        data: <? php echo $FB; ?>
    };

    function createChart() {

        chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container'
            },

            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 4
            },

            yAxis: {
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return (this.value > 0 ? '+' : '') + this.value + '%';
                    }
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 2,
                    color: 'silver'
                }]
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    compare: 'percent'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.change}%)<br/>',
                valueDecimals: 2
            },
            series: seriesOptions
        });
    }
});
```

If you have any questions or need further information, please let me know with a comment.

Thanks

BTW: I have all necessary assets included for Highcharts to work; when I replace my JS + PHP with example code from the Highcharts site, it works beautifully. So the problem clearly lies in my JS + PHP code.

Comment: Do you have quotes around MSFT, AAPL and FB in your seriesOptions code? Fairly confident that that would throw errors for undefined variables.

Comment: @MatthewKremer Thanks, just made that change. Still not working, but yes that was an error on my part.

Comment: Hmmm...I tried copying your code and putting it into JSFiddle (just replacing the PHP echo's with static arrays) and it worked fine. Could you run the code, and view the HTML source of the page after the php is all done and put it on here?

Comment: Interesting... here is the HTML source that I'm getting: http://urldt.com/283066-419140

Comment: Ah, I think I found the problem, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, I believe I found the problem, it lies in the way that you are storing each individual point in the array.

Instead of this (which is passing a string x,y separated by a comma):

```
strtotime($val['Date']) * 1000 . ', ' . (float)$val['Close'];
```

You are going to want to use something like this ([Highcharts accepts arrays or associative arrays](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data)):

```
array((strtotime($val['Date']) * 1000), ((float)$val['Close']));
```

That will store the X and Y variables as an array instead of comma separated string for the javascript to pass as data.

Comment: thank you but that did not seem to remedy my situation. I think the problem may be that my data arrays are all wrapped in a containing array. For instance, right now it looks like: [[foo,bar],[qux,baz]] when it should be [foo,bar],[qux,baz]. Does that seem like it could be causing the problem? If so, how can I fix?

Comment: @585connor No, that is how it should be. It's an array of x,y coordinate arrays. Just curious, right now you have the chart initializing inside of a createChart(); Are you calling that function afterwards? You could probably even remove the function part and just immediately initialize the chart = Highcharts....

Comment: Thanks @MatthewKremer, the chart now displays but it only shows one set of data (FB) instead of all three that I had loaded. Any idea what might be causing that?

Comment: Ah, I see you moved the PHP part down directly into the Series, good idea. Each Series has to be in it's own set of curly brackets. So it should be [{name: 'MSFT', data: [stuff]},{name: 'AAPL', data: [stuff]},{name: 'FB', data: [stuff]}]

Comment: Unfortunately no, still getting only one series to appear on the chart. Also, with that one series, I'm not able to hover over the chart and "inspect" different data points like in this example: http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/compare

Comment: Let's focus on just getting everything to show up first. Could you give me another HTML snippet of everything updated?

Comment: Not sure which you meant so here's a link to how it looks now: http://bit.ly/15D3Dhi and here's the code: http://urldt.com/121809-598040

Comment: That's very strange. I can see yours works and when I copy your data into my series it works for my chart too, but there seems to be something wrong with my data or how it is structured. FB data comes through fine, but AAPL and MSFT do not show up. Could it be because the AAPL and MSFT data arrays are MUCH longer?

Comment: Possibly. But I think we solved the initial problem you were having. I'd call this one done and open a new question or google around for reasons that might be happening.